# AWS SES Suppression list issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Recently I got a delivery issue on SES, the configuration is good, and there is only one user not getting emails. I checked the email and the reason why is not getting the emails is this one:

```
Action: failed 
Remote-MTA: dns; amazonses.com 
Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxxx@mydomain.com 
Diagnostic-Code: Amazon SES did not send the message to this address because it is on the suppression list for your account. For more information about removing addresses from the suppression list, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-suppression-list.html Status: 5.1.1
```

All good until here, the thing is when I checked the suppression list, the email address is not there.

What am I missing here? Any idea about where else to take a look?

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please add the output of `aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations` to your question? Please run it using the exact credentials that were originally used to obtain the above error.

Comment: Thanks  Ermiya Eskandary!... As I mentioned in my posted I checked and the address is not there, is there a match for the domain, another account but not for the particular address.

Comment: Status 5.1.1 means email address not found - can you even send an email to this email via your personal email? Seems like it's an email that does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I am able to send emails to this account

Comment: SES is regional, did you run ```aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations``` in the right region?